# How can I test a class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class like this

```
public class BonusImageHandler
{   private static IStorageProvider _storageProvider;
    private static Type storageProviderType;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
    private static IStorageProvider StorageProvider
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_storageProvider == null)
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        _storageProvider = (IStorageProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(storageProviderType);
                    }
                }
            }
            return _storageProvider;
        }
    }

    public BonusImageHandler(string providerTypeName)
    {
        storageProviderType = Type.GetType(providerTypeName);
    }

   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
        //do some thing here
    }

    private static string ParseInputs(string baseUrl, string imageType)
    {
      //do other things
     }
}
```

the constructor is not static because it takes a string as an argument and the property private static IStorageProvider StorageProvider is a static one. Team leader told me it will not work this way, why?? how can I test it?? how can I pass the httpContext to the ProcessRequest function.
I'm sorry for this silly question but I'm still a beginner.

Comment: First of all, it should take `HttpContextBase`.

Comment: Why are you `lock(_lock)` twice in a row in a single method?

Comment: (1) What do you want to test? (2) What is not working? (3) On the `get`, you are locking the same object twice. Don't do this.

Comment: What is your question? "it will not work this way" is vague.

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't do it my self. I just created the constructor to be able to determine which provider type I can use. the original code was like that

Comment: private static IStorageProvider StorageProvider
        {  get
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_storageProvider == null)
                    {
                        lock (_lock)
                        {
                         var storageProviderType = Type.GetType(StorageProviderTypeName);
                            _storageProvider = (IStorageProvider) Activator.CreateInstance(storageProviderType);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _storageProvider;
            }
        }

Comment: @Bazzz Why it will not work?? I'm asking this question because I don't know. I don't know even how to test it to see whether it works or now. Can you tell me what is wrong and how to test??

Comment: @MuhammadA.Fareed all that is covered in the first 5 lines of my answer... it doesn't work because what you explicitly tell `x` to use is not necessarily what `x` uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bad because an *instance* constructor assigns the *static* field; consider:

```
var x = new BonusImageHandler("foo");
var y = new BonusImageHandler("bar");
```

now... what is the **static** `storageProviderType`, and why should that make sense? What handler does `x` use? (hint: it isn't `"foo"`).

Now consider multiple callers, perhaps on different threads, calling this seemingly at random.

Frankly, it looks like this should be more like:

```
public static void InitProvider(string providerTypeName) {...}
```

but by the time you've done that, you then start thinking maybe it should be:

```
public static void InitProvider(Type providerType) {...}
```

or even clearer:

```
public static void InitProvider(IStorageProvider provider) {...}
```

Or: just make it an instance field, so you can pass (perhaps via an IoC/DI tool) the provider into each instance separately, i.e.

```
private readonly IStorageProvider provider;
public BonusImageHandler(IStorageProvider provider) {this.provider = provider;}
```

Comment: @MarkGravell That was my original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776846/how-can-we-merge-similar-getters-together and so I did it like this.

Comment: @MuhammadA.Fareed Alex's answer is bad. Sorry. But it is.

Comment: @MarkGravell so what do you recommend me to do??

Comment: @MuhammadA.Fareed I think I already covered that in my answer, with two different approaches (one if it truly is static, and one if it is per-instance)

Comment: When I was 8 years old, teacher explained us how to divide 235 over 23 it was so easy for him, too difficult for us to understand, at this age. I think I'm now at the same stage of programming. Thank you very much, any way. I'll try to apply your suggestion.

Comment: @MuhammadA.Fareed I'm going to go with 10 and 5/23rds

Comment: @MarkGravell I think that u started to go with the right answer after some time of experience, didn't u??